# disabling navigation keys for xamNumericEditor using properties

Tags: xaml, infragistics

Is there any property to disable UP/Down keys that are incrementing/decrementing the xamNumericEditor value using any property of numericeditor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the [SpinIncrement](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/Current/CLR4.0/?page=InfragisticsWPF4.Editors.v12.2~Infragistics.Windows.Editors.XamMaskedEditor~SpinIncrement.html) property to 0 the up/down arrow keys will not affect the value of the editor.